# Why Jest cases takes much more time to run inside the Gitlab pipeline (Throw a timeout error inside pipeline)?

Tags: jestjs, gitlab, timeout, pipeline

When I run test cases in local. All the test cases are completed within time limit(5000). But, When I run those test cases in gitlab pipeline then it will consume more time.

I use gitlab version 10.

Comment: i highly recommend to provide log outputs and to compare the outputs local vs gitlab. There might be simple reasons, like caching, etc. which could speed up your build tremendously :) but without any kind of logs, it is hard to guess :)

Comment: Thanks @SimonSchrottner.

I am not able to post a screen shots. But, I  can say that It throws an timeout out error (Jest case exceeded 5000 ms). Also, I run test cases without caching.

I use gitlab and it takes 10 times more time to run in pipeline. So, basically it is a timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by

1. identify and close the open handlers by `--detectOpenHandles`.
2. Divide the test cases in chunks using `--matchPathPattern` and run those chunks parallel in GitLab pipeline. Generate separate coverage reports and merge using Istanbul-merge.